# Artificial Industrial Revolution

Tags: technological-development, history

How would someone artificially speed up a civilization's technology or cause an industrial revolution? Reading on what caused the industrial revolution in Britain makes it seem like it happened by chance due to several disparate factors. How would someone like a time traveler try and create one artificially?

Comment: Kill Genghis Khan, perhaps start a long drought in Mongolia somehow. Song China might just industrialize.

Answer (score 8):

A quick search for [causes of the industrial revolution](http://education-portal.com/academy/lesson/causes-of-the-first-industrial-revolution.html) finds a source that suggests that they were

1. The agricultural revolution.
2. A strong banking system for financing.
3. Available mineral resources.

This suggests that you could launch an industrial revolution by finding mineral resources, establishing a strong financing system, and launching an agricultural revolution.  Presumably the time traveler has some knowledge of where mineral resources can be found.  Establishing a strong financial system is a political problem.  The traveler would need to either convince the government to help or gather a group of private citizens.  So that just leaves the agricultural revolution.

According to Wikipedia, the causes of the [British Agricultural Revolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Agricultural_Revolution) were

1. Crop rotation, including winter crops rather than leaving the land fallow.
2. Improvements in the plow.
3. Switching from common farm land to owned farms.
4. Free intranational trade.
5. Improved transportation infrastructure.
6. Improved land management (irrigation, etc.).
7. Selective breeding of livestock for desired characteristics.

This is a combination of political issues (3-5) and technical issues (1-2, 6-7).  Crop rotation and selective breeding are straightforward to understand.  The Rotherham Swing Plough (British spelling intended) was patented in 1730, so it shouldn't be that hard to get the plans if the time traveler has an opportunity to prepare.  Land management would tend to improve if stressed.

Since political issues are so important, the time traveler would first have to gain political influence.  The easiest way would seem to be to arrive shortly before a historical event and predict it.  For example, if there is going to be a surprise attack, the time traveler could bring a warning and allow the leadership to prepare.

Alternately, the time traveler might bring the locations of gold mines and use that information to accrue wealth and influence.

There have been several stories describing how time travelers could launch industrial revolutions.  Eric Flint's **1632** series is one of the larger and more recent ones.

Comment: After reading [The Ascent of Money](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ascent_of_Money), I almost think that a strong financial system is all you really need.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with artificially starting an industrial revolution is the mindset of the Government of the time, and the mindset of the people.

In Britain, there was an encouragement of 'scientific thinking' and the free exchange of ideas at the time. This, coupled with the government being a Parliamentary Monarchy (in which parliament made all the rules) meant that entrepreneurship, free trade and the spreading of ideas were encouraged (as those in power could understand the importance of such things).

France also had the means of starting an industrial revolution, however at the time scientific thinking was heavily regulated (ideas could take up to a century to be published in the public domain) and there was less of a free exchange of ideas. Because of this, new ideas couldn't be quickly improved on and therefore France lacked the drive for an Industrial Revolution at the time.

Now I'm not saying what your proposing is impossible, you just have to be careful on how you go about it. Your time traveller has to ensure that those in power will both accept their ideas and allow for entrepreneurship and the free exchange of ideas.